# TSQL Xquery - Can you select the first instance of repeating nodes?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery

I have an XML document containing Trade data, some Trades can have multiple legs which mean that the XML structure is repeated. Is there a way in my XQuery I can select the first instance of repeated items?

Thanks for the first response, I've added the code for reference...

```
declare @Trade_Ref nvarchar(12)

select  @Trade_Ref = 'OTC_0000001'

declare @input xml =    (
        select  FIXML_Data
        from    dbo.OTC_FIXML_Data
        where   TradeRef = @Trade_Ref
        )               
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.fixprotocol.org/FIXML-4-4') 
update  dbo.OTC_FIXML_Data 
set TrdDt   = (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/@TrdDt)[1]', 'datetime'))               
    ,TxnTm  = (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/@TxnTm)[1]', 'datetime'))           ,Side   = (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/@Side)[1]', 'int'))         ,Qty    = (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/@Qty)[1]', 'int'))              ,TransTyp   = (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/@TransTyp)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)'))                
    ,ID2    = (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/@ID2)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)'))         ,ID = (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/Instrmt/@ID)[1]', 'nvarchar(20)'))          
    ,IndAllocID= (select @input.value('(/FIXML/Batch/AllocInstrctn/Alloc/@IndAllocID)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')) 
where TradeRef = @Trade_Ref
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the XPath in your XQuery with [1] to get the first matching item.

If that's not specific enough as answer, you might want to post the query, the data and some expected results.

Comment: Yeah, it's a subject within a subject :) Be glad of upvotes etc if it was helpful.

Comment: Also, I already have the instance number included in the query so at a loss to explain why nothing has returned?